# Datepicker target on datepicker date selected

Tags: jquery, datepicker

How I can find target when date picker is selected.

I tried

```
Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker">


   $("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',onClose:update_date(this)});

   function update_date(data)
   {
     alert($(this).parent().attr('id'));
   }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6UnTh/69/)

I expect result **datepicker** id of textbox

Thanks

Comment: Your jsfiddle and posted code does not match. What do you mean by target , could you please specify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',onClose: function(){update_date(this);}});
function update_date(data)
{
    alert($(data).attr("id"));
}
```

check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x0omgpqc/)

Comment: well it seems working, but just a request, how my fiddle is not working

Comment: your request is not working because  when you specify `onClose:update_date(this)` this actually will call function on load and will assign it's output to the onClose, so wraping it in `function(){}` we assign function to be called onClose wich in turn will call the desired function

Comment: do you mean my call will be only for page load, and function will not be called on onclose event

Comment: yes, if you try your fiddle you will notice the alert appearing only when page is loaded, then after closing datepicker by selecting date will not alert any thing

Answer (score 2):

Try using `onClose` this way :

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',onClose: function(dateText, inst){ console.log(inst.id); }});  //this will give 'id' as 'datepicker'
```

Fiddle :- http://jsfiddle.net/gahrfdfj/

OR This is working fine :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',onClose: function () {
    update_date(this);
}});

function update_date(data)
{
 alert(data.id);
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var myDate = $("#datepicker");
myDate.datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
myDate.change(update_date);

function update_date()
{
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
}
```

See the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DanielBank/y5hcovoq/)